# Defining operators and testing for null

Tags: c#

I have a class in C# where I define the operator ==. The method I have currently throws an object is null exception when testing the following

```
MyClass a = new MyClass(); if(a==null)....
```

This is frustrating because in the definition of the operator i can't ask if either parameter is null because it will just go into infinite recursion.

How do I test to see if either parameter is null when defining the == operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [object.ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx):

```
if (object.ReferenceEquals(objA, null)) { ... }
```

Another option is to cast `objA` to `object`:

```
if ((object)objA == null) { ... }
```

You may want to consult these [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.ReferenceEquals(objA, null)`.